# Migrate site from one hosting to another make theme lost styles and others

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I migrate my Magento site from one hosting to another and now I loose all my theme styles and so on. Should I change paths in somewhere? I check /app/etc/local.xml but doesn’t find any there. Also I check core_config_data at DB level and again doesn’t find nothing. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking file and directory permissions? Maybe the `skin` directory is not accessible. Apart of that, you have to set permissions to the media directory and subdirectories to allow Magento to write product thumbnail images there.

Comment: No, I didn't setup permissions but one moment even if I don't add nothing new meaning products or something else with images it's necessary to setup permissions?

Comment: When you chance hosting, it's necessary to setup permissions so that Magento can read everything and write to certain directories. The simplest way to check if it's a permission problem would be to set everything to 777 for a moment (writable by everyone), but keep in mind that leaving it like this would be a major security flaw. Generally, directories should be set to 775 and files to 644, but it all depends on the groups and owner of the files.

Comment: Another thing you can do it to check your paths. Open the page, view the source or inspect the page with Developer Tools/Firebug, copy some CSS path and try to open it directly in your browser.